# Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, clob

I am using Hibernate 3.5.6 with Oracle 10g. I am seeing the below exception during initialization but the application itself is working fine. What is the cause for this exception? and how it can be corrected?

**Exception**
Disabling contextual LOB creation as `createClob()` method threw error : `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

**Info**
Oracle version: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 
JDBC driver: Oracle JDBC driver, version: 11.1.0.7.0

Comment: "the application itself is working fine"... as long as you don't try using LOBs, I imagine.

Answer (score 81):

Disable this warning by adding property below.

For Spring application:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Normal JPA:

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Comment: Which java version did you try this with? Intellij is unable to find this property.

Comment: We tried with eclipse as well as Intellij. In both cases its working.Actually, we tired with java 6, 7,8 and its working without any problem for us. Just debug your code or cross check your code.

Answer (score 67):

As you noticed, this exception isn't a real problem. It happens during the boot, when Hibernate tries to retrieve some meta information from the database. If this annoys you, you can disable it:

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults false
```

Comment: Thanks Partenon. I am aware of the option to disable it,but I am trying to find the reason for this exception. Any pointers?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it's not a problem with your application, Hibernate is just verifying if the DB supports some features and adjusting itself in case it doesn't. I would verify if any mapping is triggering this (like a LOB field), but it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using this solution with Oracle is **dangerous**! It leads to **unexpected COMMITs**. When hibernate creates temporary tables it has to open a new transaction, since DDL statements in Oracle DB imply COMMIT. By setting this option to false you disable opening new transaction and DDL get issues within your transaction COMMITing it.

Comment: @BorisBrodski , are you sure the behavior you described is caused by setting this property to false? Looking at the code, I don't see anything extra being executed when this is false: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/f19c8e995a763fe7c31fbb7f5777ac6ff608c215/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/env/internal/JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java#L76 .

Comment: @jpkrohling Yes, I debugged hibernate4.2.7 and saw if myself: Setting `useJdbcMetadata` to `false` prevents `metaReportsDDLCausesTxnCommit` to be set and it stays `false`! http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.2.Final/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/JdbcServicesImpl.java

Comment: Works fine. Put this line on file persistence.xml

Answer (score 28):

Looking at the comments in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.4-Final/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/JdbcSupportLoader.java#JdbcSupportLoader.useContextualLobCreation%28java.sql.Connection%29):

> Basically here we are simply checking
>   whether we can call the
>   java.sql.Connection methods for LOB
>   creation added in JDBC 4. We not only
>   check whether the java.sql.Connection
>   declares these methods, but also
>   whether the actual java.sql.Connection
>   instance implements them (i.e. can be
>   called without simply throwing an
>   exception).

So, it's trying to determine if it can use some new JDBC 4 methods.  I guess your driver may not support the new LOB creation method.

Comment: Does it mean that `Driver does not support LOB feature` or `Database does not support LOB feature` ?

Comment: @MarekSebera Driver. I'm having this problem because something is mysteriously overriding my C3P0 library with an ancient version. The database supports it just fine.

Answer (score 24):

In order to hide the exception:

For Hibernate 5.2 (and Spring Boot 2.0), you can either use the *use_jdbc_metadata_defaults* property that the others pointed out:

```
# Meant to hide HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Or, if you want to not have any side effects from the above setting (there's a comment warning us about some Oracle side effects, I don't know if it's valid or not), you can just disable the logging of the exception like this:

```
logging:
   level: 
      # Hides HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error 
      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl: WARN
```

Answer (score 22):

To get rid of the exception

```
INFO - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error :java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` file Add below property

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

Comment: This is the same answer as from Steve K. Why do you answer it again?

Comment: @Bevor he explain the problem but I gave answer.

Comment: You only want to command updates by copying an already given answer. Your answer doesn't distinguish from Steve K.

Comment: Thanks. Based on this, I added `<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />`  to the `persistence.xml` file and it solved the issue for me. I use JPA with Hibernate.

Comment: @Bevor to be honest for a novice like me this answer is much clearer in part where should i put this property

Answer (score 15):

Update to this for using Hibernate 4.3.x / 5.0.x - you could just set this property to true:

```
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</prop>
```

to get rid of that error message. Same effect but without the "threw exception" detail.
See LobCreatorBuilder source for details.

Comment: set this in persistence.xml

Comment: You can set it there, if you use e.g. spring to setup the PU you (can) set it in springs configuration space - so it depends ;).

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in other comments using

`hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false`

...will fix the annoying message, but can lead to many other surprising problems. Better solution is just to disable contextual LOB creation with this:

`hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true`

This will cause Hibernate (in my case, its 5.3.10.Final) to skip probing the JDBC driver and just output following message:

`HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true`

So far it looks like this setting doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 10):

Just add below line in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

Answer (score 5):

Updating JDBC driver to the lastest version removed the nasty error message.

You can download it from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Free registration is required though.

Answer (score 4):

If you set:

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

it can cause you troubles with PostgreSQL when your table name contains reserved word like user. After insert it will try to find id sequence with:

```
select currval('"user"_id_seq');
```

which will obviously fail. This at least with Hibernate 5.2.13 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1. Haven't found other way to prevent this message so now just ignoring it.

Answer (score 4):

When working with Spring boot 2.1.x this warning message appears when starting up the application.

As indicated here, maybe this problem didn't show up in earlier versions because the related property was set to true by default and now it is false:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12007

In consequence, solving this is as simple as adding the following property to the spring application.property file.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
```

Comment: Thanks for this. An exception trace in log INFO mode is really annoying!

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because of you didn't choose the appropriate JDBC. Just download and use the JDBC for oracle 10g rather than 11g.

Comment: Huh. This completely contradicts the response of Boris Brodski. You sure this makes any difference?

Answer (score 2):

I am using hibernate 5.3.17 and it works fine by adding given properties

```
hibernate.default_entity_mode=dynamic-map
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error when my web app was started in Linux by user logged in with insufficient access rights. This error

> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000424:
>   Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error :
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

usually preceded by other errors / exceptions, especially from your application server i.e 
for Tomcat:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component ...

or

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  ... cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Solution:

1. Stop your web apps current instance.
2. Login with super user or those with sufficient access rights i.e root
3. Restart your web app or call previous function again.

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone who is facing this problem with Spring Boot 2**

by default spring boot was using hibernate 5.3.x version, I have added following property in my pom.xml

```
<hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
```

and error was gone. Reason for error is already explained in posts above

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jacek Prucia, setting the `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false`, will bring other "surprising problems", one of them is the batch inserts will stop working..

Answer (score -1):

Remove @Temporal annotations if you use it with java.sql.* classes.

Answer (score -3):

Check if you are not on a VPN.  I had the same issue but realized the db I was connecting to remote!