# Why are my RequestMapping not being picked up when deploying on Standalone Tomcat? It works in Eclipse WTP

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am deploying a Spring MVC webapp on Tomcat8 using RequestMapping annotation.
Example of Mappings:

```
@Controller("brandController")
@RequestMapping("brand")
public class BrandController {

@Autowired
private BrandService brandService;


/**
 * Creates or edits details about a specific Brand
 * @param brand the brand to create/edit
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/save", consumes="application/json",  produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Brand editBrand(@RequestBody Brand brand){
    brandService.saveBrand(brand);
    return brand;
}
...
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

web.xml is referencing WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, which has the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.web.controller"/>


<!-- Data Source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Production Environment -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.xx/mydb"/>
    <property name="user" value="myuser"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypass" />

    <!-- c3p0 properties -->

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600"/><!-- seconds -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="6"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.acme.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>


<!-- scan for Spring MVC components -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>



</beans>
```

catalina.out logs are the following (loglevel = INFO)

```
    26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.459 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.521 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.524 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.525 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.526 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2574 ms
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.601 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.680 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /home/me/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/ACME.war
26-Jan-2015 13:10:41.713 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
26-Jan-2015 13:10:47.897 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [112] milliseconds.
2015-01-26 13:10:48,187 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:484) - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
2015-01-26 13:10:48,218 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] support.AbstractApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:510) - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 26 13:10:48 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-01-26 13:10:48,274 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:317) - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2015-01-26 13:10:49,172 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] log.MLog (MLog.java:92) - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2015-01-26 13:10:49,206 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] c3p0.C3P0Registry (C3P0Registry.java:216) - Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:49.604 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
26-Jan-2015 13:10:49.620 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
26-Jan-2015 13:10:49.625 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
26-Jan-2015 13:10:49.629 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-01-26 13:10:50,015 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource (AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:522) - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge2vb97an867f5dlj3r|2341b2f0, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge2vb97an867f5dlj3r|2341b2f0, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx/mydb, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 6, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.102 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.123 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.208 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.222 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.<init> HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.487 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate HHH000229: Running schema validator
26-Jan-2015 13:10:52.487 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2015-01-26 13:10:52,574 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager (HibernateTransactionManager.java:360) - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge2vb97an867f5dlj3r|2341b2f0, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge2vb97an867f5dlj3r|2341b2f0, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx/mydb, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 6, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2015-01-26 13:10:53,555 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:518) - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 26 13:10:48 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-01-26 13:10:53,604 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:518) - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 26 13:10:48 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-01-26 13:10:53,670 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver (ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:278) - Did not find any ViewResolvers to delegate to; please configure them using the 'viewResolvers' property on the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
2015-01-26 13:10:53,701 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:503) - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 5512 ms
26-Jan-2015 13:10:54.334 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:54.339 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Jan-2015 13:10:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 12817 ms
```

Now if I deploy my application through Eclipse WTP, the mappings are picked up and the application works correctly.
However, when I deploy the application in a "plain" Tomcat 8 container, the mappings are not picked up.

Note that the runtime package of Tomcat is exactly the same, the only difference is that once I used it from within Eclipse and the other
Libs and classes deployed in WEB-INF are the same, so I suspect this has to do with some settings being customized by Eclipse, but I couldn't find any relevant difference.

Would you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: do you use maven or something like that ? do you have some error logs ?

Comment: When you deploy a war directly into tomcat, then the mapping for the servlet will be the war file name (without ".war" and except it is named ROOT.war), when you deploy the application from within Eclipse, then this mappling can been a different. - What I want to say, is, check first that the url you use in the browser, is "forwared" to the application in Tomcat (for example by invoking a static resource)

Comment: @Ralph I am able  to access my ACME/apage.jsp correctly, so it should not be an issue with path

Comment: @vincent  I added some logs. Also, yes, I am using Maven to manage the project

Comment: The logs show no spring activity at all. Is does your war contain all the compiled classes, web.xml and libs?

Comment: Sometimes your app did not start correctly when the database connection fails. Do you know why you have 
contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Comment: @Ralph correct, in fact i posted the wrong section of the log. Apologies. It is  fixed now

Comment: @vincent that should not be the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588755/hibernate-disabling-contextual-lob-creation-as-createclob-method-threw-error/4592863

Comment: I do not think that this is the cause, but I am wondery why you have the line `2015-01-26 13:10:53,555 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:518) - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 26 13:10:48 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your controller in another module? maybe eclipse it deploying it as classes and when you make war file it is not in current classes folder any more?

p.s: i think it was problem with resources. can not find any reason why it can be the cause with classes. anyway :D

Comment: and we have a winner| Silly me, I didn't check the content of the WAR file Eclipse was producing. Some class files were missing from it. `mvn package` did the job.
Probably my project is not super-clean as we worked with Netbeans on the same project, that's why eclipse misbehaves

Comment: did i win? what did i win ? :D. oh. i win your reputation. what a shame, u only have 5 remained. it feels like stealing. but it feels good to win something :D