# Tomcat + Spring deploying error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I need help. I run spring java server under tomcat.

```
2-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] 

org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.20.0
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Bosun\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_beautifulmindonlineserver
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Bosun\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.20
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Bosun\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_beautifulmindonlineserver\conf\logging.properties
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Bosun\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_beautifulmindonlineserver
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Bosun\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.20
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Bosun\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\temp
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.12] using APR version [1.5.2].
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
02-Sep-2017 10:35:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:53.641 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.280 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.311 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.327 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.327 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2528 ms
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.405 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.405 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.436 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.452 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
02-Sep-2017 10:35:54.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 125 ms
Connected to server
[2017-09-02 10:35:54,889] Artifact beautifulmindonlineserver:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
02-Sep-2017 10:36:00.224 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
02-Sep-2017 10:36:02.938 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
02-Sep-2017 10:36:03.281 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
02-Sep-2017 10:36:03.281 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate}
02-Sep-2017 10:36:03.578 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
02-Sep-2017 10:36:04.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Bosun\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\manager]
02-Sep-2017 10:36:04.561 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Bosun\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps\manager] has finished in [94] ms
02-Sep-2017 10:36:04.873 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
02-Sep-2017 10:36:05.450 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-Sep-2017 10:36:05.450 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4d851601
02-Sep-2017 10:36:07.774 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
02-Sep-2017 10:36:07.774 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
02-Sep-2017 10:36:07.821 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2017-09-02 10:36:07,868] Artifact beautifulmindonlineserver:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

hybernate.properties file

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

I found that if I comment this line 
       public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository {
    }
in UserRepository file related to my User ORM class, everything compiled well.

My dependencies:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Web-->
        <!--Json converter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

As I am novice in server-side development and spring, ask for extended response.

**UPDATED**:

```
package com.blackbosun.beatufilmind.server;

import com.blackbosun.beatufilmind.server.config.WebConfig;
import com.blackbosun.beatufilmind.server.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private final static String DISPATCHER = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your server settings or the method that starts tomcat?

Comment: @gmwagner see updated, please

Comment: Since your were getting the error: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error I would try [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588755/disabling-contextual-lob-creation-as-createclob-method-threw-error).

It doesn't look like a Spring issue.