# Reason for "Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error"

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I understand the below is not a show stopper and we can live with it.

> Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Also, I am able to suppress it using this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508897/2046462).

But why exactly we are getting that exception in the first place?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588755/disabling-contextual-lob-creation-as-createclob-method-threw-error - It suggests it is outdated JDBC driver

Answer (score 1):

For me this error came with Postgres DB. In this case add in your file 
***application.properties*** this line:

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question wasn't how to fix the problem, which they already knew, but what was actually going on with it. I'd like to know that too.