# What does "contextual lob creation" mean in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

There are plenty of questions and answers about how to disable it when it is causing an error, but what does this feature do exactly?

Comment: What is the source of that term?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - It appears to be a Hibernate thing. "Contextual LOB creation" is probably using `createClob` (or similar) within a [contextual session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/architecture-current-session.html).

Comment: @GordThompson I think so too, but the OP should clarify what he means or in what context he read it, because looking at JDBC itself, it is not a JDBC term and so it doesn't really mean anything "in JDBC".

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this post: [Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588755/disabling-contextual-lob-creation-as-createclob-method-threw-error)

There you can fond the source comments

> Basically here we are simply checking whether we can call the java.sql.Connection methods for LOB creation added in JDBC 4. We not only check whether the java.sql.Connection declares these methods, but also whether the actual java.sql.Connection instance implements them (i.e. can be called without simply throwing an exception).

Comment: The question is not how to disable it but what that feature _is_? I know what are C/B/LOBs (Large Objects), but what is contextual lob creation?