# H2: always try to create tabes with file database

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have configured the application-local.yml like this to do some tests in local:

```yaml
    spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:file:./data/db-test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        username: dbtest
        password: dbtest
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
      jpa:
        show-sql: true
        generate-ddl: false
        properties:
          # to prevent this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588755/disabling-contextual-lob-creation-as-createclob-method-threw-error
          hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults : false
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
      h2:
        console:
          enabled: true
          path: /public/h2-console
      liquibase:
        enabled: false
```

The first time the server is started, I see some logs from Hibernate to create tables and the file for the database is created.
The issue is that when I restart the server, I have some errors because it tries to create again the same tables, constraints... I have the ddl-auto set to update so I do not understand why. I tried to update the `generate-ddl` value to false but it is the same.

Here is an exemple of what I have:

```
Hibernate: create table myTable (id bigint not null, ..., primary key (id))
15:59:49.252 [restartedMain] WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table myTable (id bigint not null, ..., primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table myTable(id bigint not null, ..., primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Can you try setting `hibernate.ddl-auto: none` and see if that fixes it? If not, are you sure the configuration file is loaded?

Comment: By setting `ddl-auto` to none, then no update will be done if I update an entity right? I would like to keep the update of the H2 database if I add or update an entity.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I just wanted to make sure the configuration file is actually loaded. This is just a debugging step and you should change the value later

Comment: I tried and with none there is no error when the server starts.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true` is forcing spring data JPA to recreate the tables. Just set this to false or delete the key as the default is false. This should fix the Problem. [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.jpa.generate-ddl)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is the same with generate-ddl set to false. I set an example of error.